# how i get string path of device with usb4java?

Tags: java, usb4java

I want to get the name or path of the USB disk for Linux, Windows and Mac using usb4java 1.3.0.
Does anyone know how to get this path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this issue](https://github.com/usb4java/usb4java-javax/issues/10) on GitHub. It is not currently supported.